# PHP SQL division by zero Warning but is not zero

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a trouble.
I have a SQL table with processes which are finalized, closed, cancelled and working on, which also are associateds by an area (talent, outsourcing, digital, etc).
I want to do an AVG by the area and total by the states of the processes.
so i have:

```
$tiempoQueryFinalizados = mysqli_query($con,
 "SELECT IFNULL(SUM(IFNULL(timestampdiff(DAY,fecha_creacion,IFNULL(fecha_cerrado,NOW())),0)),0) AS finalizados, 
    (Select count(id_proceso) from proceso where estado ='FINALIZADO' and fecha_cerrado is not null) as c 
  FROM proceso 
  WHERE estado = 'FINALIZADO' and fecha_cerrado IS NOT NULL and area ='".$rowArea['id_area']."' ");
```

Then I use a simple division in PHP with

`mysqli_fetch_assoc($tiempoQueryFinalizados)['finalizados'] / mysqli_fetch_assoc($tiempoQueryFinalizados)['c']`

but I get the error `Warning: Division by zero`, so I check if was zero but it doesn't. In this example `mysqli_fetch_assoc($tiempoQueryFinalizados)['c'] = 2` but still counting as 0

any help, please?

EDIT: the area is returned by a fetch array of `$areaQuery = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from area where id_area!=0");`

Comment: `mysqli_fetch_assoc($tiempoQueryFinalizados)['finalizados']` is null or zero.

Comment: yup, sometimes, but still 0/2 = 0

Comment: How many rows do you expect to be returned by that query??

Comment: The second call to `mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches a second row from the query. The value from the second row might be zero or if there isn't a second row, it could well be null.

Comment: only returns 1 row, a Sum of the processes, and the count of all procesess with this status.

Comment: @RobForrest That's it! I forgot this thing. I modified  ````$tiempoQueryFinalizados = mysqli_query(...``` by ```$tiempoQueryFinalizados = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(... ``` and did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: @Ian you can divide 0/2, but you can't 2/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a simple division

```
mysqli_fetch_assoc($tiempoQueryFinalizados)['finalizados'] / 
mysqli_fetch_assoc($tiempoQueryFinalizados)['c']
```

Each call to `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` gets a new row from your resultset. So as the query only returns one row, the second call will return FALSE which equates to zero.

So this would be a better way of doing the retrieval and calculation

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($tiempoQueryFinalizados);
$calc = $row['finalizados']] / $row['c'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I forgot when **every call** you do to `mysqli_fetch*` you are jumping to **the next register**, so only I needed to edit

`$tiempoQueryFinalizados = mysqli_query(...`

by

`$tiempoQueryFinalizados = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query(...`

now 

`$tiempoQueryFinalizados['finalizados'] / $tiempoQueryFinalizados['c']`

works very nice :)
thank you all!